# We Won't Lose Against

Tags: meaning, grammar

https://dianeravitch.net/2014/12/03/how-to-survive-and-prevail-in-this-era-of-greed-and-privatization/

According to the article, can we say;

*"We won't lose against this era"* or *"This era won't prevail against us"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** say "We won't lose against this era" or "This era won't prevail against us"; but that does not accurately reflect your source's use.

*Era* in the article's title signifies a timespan, and *in this era ...* is a temporal locative expression: it tells **when** we survive and prevail, not what we survive or what we prevail against.

If you speak of "losing against" this era or of the era "prevailing" against you, you are using *era* in a different sense: the environment in which you live during the timespan, the tendencies which are dominant during the timespan, the forces you encounter during the timespan.

Comment: Actually, what I meant is in your second paragraph. So, can I replace this era with the era?

Comment: You **can** say anything you want--but what is it you want? Paraphrase the title, or express the content, or what?